# Why is the display on my Acer Aspire 3820T-6480 darker than usual?

Tags: display, ubuntu-14.04, backlight

I have an [Acer Aspire 3820T-6480](http://www.cnet.com/products/acer-aspire-timelinex-3820t-6480-13-3-core-i3-380m-windows-7-home-premium-64-bit-4-gb-ram-500-gb-hdd/specs/) running Ubuntu 14.04 with an external monitor. I just restarted it after some updates and after the restart I noticed that the built-in display—AU Optronics (Model No: B133XW01 V.3)—was darker than usual but the external monitor was the same as usual.

My first instinct is a dead backlight, but I just replaced the display a couple months ago.

Is there something else that could be causing this? Or if not is there something that could have caused the backlight to die so fast?

Comment: Sure thing. Just let me look that up. It'll take a few minutes

Comment: Alright, I added the screen details

Answer (score 0):

Well I fixed it. It seems it was just a loose connection. After disconnecting and reconnecting the display the backlight started working again.